# Storing integers in preference class

Tags: android, integer, sharedpreferences, preference

In my android app I have created a preference class(which extends PreferenceActivity) for storing about 10 integer values. I am not creating any xml file for that activity in R.xml as I don't want it. I just need to store 10 integer variables in this file(which can save it even after exit) and I want to get these values from another activity, perform some changes to the preferences, then save the preference class.

My queries are:

1. How can I store an integer variable in preference class?
2. How to call that variable from another activity?
3. How to return that variable again to preference class?

Comment: Paste some code you wrote to show us that you have tried something !

Comment: Use PreferenceManager to store and restore your preference values. From PreferenceManager you can obtain SharedPreferences (in SharedPreferences you can store N number of variables, including ints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here i added sample code for SharedPreferences for you concern .please try this code and let me know. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

**SharedPreferences Creation:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**Store the values to SharedPreferences:**

```
int userId = 2425;
String authtoken = "abcdef345345";
String authkey = "qrst";
sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS",prefMode);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = vSmileSharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("AUTH_KEY", authkey);
editor.putString("AUTH_TOKEN", authtoken);
editor.putString("USER_ID", String.valueOf(userId));
editor.commit();
```

**Retriving SharedPreferences values from another Activity:**

```
String authtoken ="";
String authkey = "";
int UserId = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedPref =  getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
authtoken = sharedPref.getString("AUTH_TOKEN", null);
authkey = sharedPref.getString("AUTH_KEY", null);
UserId = sharedPref.getString("USER_ID", 0);
```

If the SharedPreference UserID is null or empty means it will take default as 0;