# How to initialize a SharedPreferences Object in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I am developing Android Application that uses push notifications to get notifications even the application is closed and save them using sharedpreferences, I have created a broadcast receiver class and initialized the sharedpreferences object that I was defined in another class called Register inside onReceive() as following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Register.preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(arg0, arg1);
    // Register.listPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(arg0, arg1);

    Register.notificationList = new ArrayList<NotificationBody>();

    Register.preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Register.listPreferences= PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String action = intent.getAction();

    int getSize = Register.preferences.getInt("listSize", 0);
    Editor edit = Register.listPreferences.edit();
```

the notifications work when the application is already open but when the application is closed and I try to send a notification, the application show a Force Close message and I saw a NullPointerException in the logcat, I suppose the problem comes from initializing the sharedpreferences object, so is there another way to initialize that object correctly in the broadcast receiver?

Comment: it's another class extended from activity

Comment: why do you need that here??

Comment: I need it as when a notification is being received, I save it immediately in in a shared preferences object.

Comment: you can get the same shareed preference object again in activity no need to refer it from receiver

Answer (score 0):

the error is not because of `context` it's because of `Register` activity try changing your code to:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Register.preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(arg0, arg1);
    // Register.listPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(arg0, arg1);

    ArrayList<NotificationBody> notificationList = new ArrayList<NotificationBody>();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences listPreferences= PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String action = intent.getAction();

    int getSize = preferences.getInt("listSize", 0);
    Editor edit = listPreferences.edit();
```

also `preferences` and  `listPreferences` seems to have same value I don't know why both.

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` will return same preference object every time.

Answer (score 0):

vipul is right. It is because your app relies on an Activity class, which most likely is destroyed when app is closed.

I just want to give an example of how you could ease the read/write of shared preferences using a helper class:

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getString(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you suggest to make such this class and call its method in my receiver to initialize the preferences?

Comment: yep.. it only needs the application context, which is provided by the onReceive method. This way you can access the preferences anywhere with a context.

Comment: I added the helper class, but even after I added it and close the application and try to send a notification, it shows me a force close and the same error null pointer exception, it didn't work.

Comment: Would you mind posting the logcat together with your current code then?

Answer (score 0):

i already added how to use shared preferences in android.Please check my answer. Hope it should helpful for you. Please let me know. If you need more clarification. Thanks

[Shared Prefernces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245083/storing-integers-in-preference-class/21249802#21249802)

Comment: Unfortunately Jeba no, the problem seems when I receive a new notification which is a text and I try to save it in a shared preferences object that is not initialized because the application is not open and this means that the context object that is used in the initializing process is null too.

Comment: Hi 3mR did you registered the Broadcast register in AndroidManifest.xml? If not means please register as like <receiver android:name="YourBroascastReceiverName">                     
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: yes, I registered it, the receiver works in both cases (application open or closed) the problem only is when the application is closed and I need to initialize the shared preference object