# My application got crashed because of not initializing the view

Tags: android

Here, i am trying to call setText method but my application is getting crashed because of some initialization problem.

```
EditText edittext;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        settings= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(settings.contains("sharedString")){
        String returnString=settings.getString("sharedString","Couldn't load the data");
        edittext.setText(returnString);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Debugging does not work by just thinking. Please post your LogCat.

Comment: where you are initializing `edittext` before calling `edittext.setText` method?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя: Pack that into an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: i have uploaded full code.please check it out .!

Comment: post `logcat` output.

Comment: Where you initialize your edit-text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edittext` is not initialized. Initialize it in `onCreate`.

In `onCreate` you have

```
edittext.setText(returnString); // not initialized in onCreate
```

You have

```
edittext =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message); // initialized in sendMessage
```

in `sendMessage`. So you may be setting text to edittext even before it is initialized

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);        
    settings= getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("sharedString", "Shared Preference Data");
    editor.commit();
    String returnString=settings.getString("sharedString","Couldn't load the data");
    edittext.setText(returnString);
}
```

Before to use the code first look about thee shared Preferences and their examples.

[SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[SharedPreferences Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245083/storing-integers-in-preference-class/21249802#21249802)

Hope it should work. Please let me know.If it not working means tell me what you want to do actually.

Comment: yeas sir,i declared settings variable as public ..and you are talking about declaring it as a local. does it really make any difference

Comment: No you added the code as settings =  getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   instead of settings =  getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  I don't know you created the edittext or not.But you are trying to set the text as edittext.setText(returnString);
If you are not created the edittext means create EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext); and then
edittext.setText(returnString);

Answer (score 0):

its a very common mistake .. I should initialize the editText before calling a method on it by

edittext =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);